# How do I work with Auth from AWS-Amplify in componentised functions?

Tags: typescript, aws-amplify

**Problem:** When trying to use `Auth` from AWS-Amplify in componentised functions in a separate `helper.ts` file, I receive an error.

**Useage:** `employerID: Auth.user.attributes["custom:id"],`

**Error:** `Property 'user' is private and only accessible within class 'AuthClass'.ts(2341)`

So, in the main file that hydrates the page, I now pass `Auth` as a prop to the function. For example: `await listEmployerImagesDetails (Auth);`, but `Auth` is defined as `any` in the function.

**Full Code Example:**
*helpers.ts*

```
export const listEmployerImagesDetails = async(Auth: any, nextToken: string) => {
    try {
        const images = await API.graphql({
             employerID: Auth.user.attributes["custom:id"],
             ...
            },
          });

          return {...}

    } catch (error){
        ...
    }
};
```

**Questions:**

1. How do I use Auth in detached functions? *(preferred choice)*
2. If this is not possible, how do I use `AuthClass` or something of that nature to ensure I'm passing in `Auth` in the correct prop location and following Typescripts type-safe benefit?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following if it is with NextJS API:

```
import { Amplify, withSSRContext } from 'aws-amplify'

...

//If is used with NextJS API 
//the Auth can be obtained from NextApiRequest,
//otherwise you can skip the line below
const { Auth } = withSSRContext({ req })

user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
console.log('user sub attribute: ', user["attributes"]["sub"])
```

If is used directly in the NextJS page this is the code:

```
import { withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react'
import { Amplify, Auth } from 'aws-amplify'
import aws_exports from 'aws-exports'

Amplify.configure(aws_exports)
...
const Ssr: NextPage = () => {
  const [refreshToken, setRefreshToken] = useState('')

  var user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()

  return (
    <div >
      ...
    </div>
  )
}

export default withAuthenticator(Ssr, { hideSignUp: true })
```

Comment: Where does the `req` come from?

Comment: If the amplify is used with NextJS API then the `req` is `NextApiRequest`. Otherwise you can use it directly, without obtaining it.